# How to schedule push notification to run at a certain time in python with heroku

Tags: python, rest, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, pyfcm

I am new to python and this is my first REST project with flask. I am trying to integrate the REST to mobile apps. What I am trying to do is to consider a booking app that places an order to the REST api. the booking object has a date that represents the date of the booking(date in the future). What i want is when my python resource is called, add booking object in DB and schedule firebase push notification to be sent to phone on the given date. 
  Everything works like a charm, except my scheduled notification. I am integrating PyFCM. If i create a endpoint to trigger the notification it works fine but to schedule it not. After researching on the internet i found out that i can use APScheduler from flask_apscheduler lib. I have a app.py file that looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from resources.trip import TripResource, TripsList, SearchTripsByDestinations
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from resources.userResource import UserLogin, UserRegister, UserResource, UserConfirm, UserLogout
from resources.booking import Booking, BookingList, TripBookings, BookingPay, DeleteBooking
from resources.seat import SeatList, SeatResource
from resources.registerTokenResource import RegisterToken, ListPaymentMethods
from resources.pushTokenResource import PushTokenResource
from ma import ma
from db import db
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler

app = Flask(__name__)
scheduler = APScheduler()
scheduler.init_app(app)
scheduler.start()


load_dotenv(".env")
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', 'sqlite:///data.db')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True
app.config['JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED'] = True 
app.config['JWT_BLACKLIST_TOKEN_CHECKS'] = ['access', 'refresh']  

api = Api(app)


jwt = JWTManager(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)


api.add_resource(TripResource, '/create_trip')
api.add_resource(TripsList, '/trips')
api.add_resource(UserRegister, '/register')
api.add_resource(UserResource, '/users')
api.add_resource(UserLogin, '/login')
api.add_resource(BookingList, '/bookings')
api.add_resource(TripBookings, '/get_trip_bookings')
api.add_resource(Booking, '/add_booking')
api.add_resource(SeatList, '/seats')
api.add_resource(BookingPay, '/book')
api.add_resource(UserConfirm, '/user_confirm/<int:user_id>')
api.add_resource(SeatResource, '/add_seats_for_booking')
api.add_resource(RegisterToken, '/add_payment_token')
api.add_resource(ListPaymentMethods, '/payment_methods')
api.add_resource(SearchTripsByDestinations, '/search_trips')
api.add_resource(DeleteBooking, '/delete_booking')
api.add_resource(UserLogout, '/logout')
api.add_resource(PushTokenResource, '/register_push_token')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from db import db

    db.init_app(app)
    db.app = app
    ma.init_app(app)

    if app.config['DEBUG']:
        @app.before_first_request
        def create_tables():
            # with app.app_context():
            db.create_all()

    app.run(port=5000)
```

for adding my booking I have a Resource file that has a post method whitch contains the folowing:

```
class Booking(Resource):

  def post(self):
        try:
            booking_item = booking_schema.load(request.get_json())
        except ValidationError as err:
            return err.messages, 500

        try:
            user = UserModel.find_by_id(booking_item.user_id)

            if booking_item.transaction_time:
                try:
                    token = PushToken.search_token_for_user(booking_item.user_id)
                    if token:
                        schedule_notif(booking_item.transaction_time, token, str(booking_item.transaction_time))

                    else:
                        return {'success': False, 'errors': ['could not send notification']}

                except Exception as e:
                    return {'success': False, 'errors': ['An error has occured scheduleing notification {}'.format(e)]}

        except Exception as err:
            return {'success': False, 'errors': ['An error has occured inserting item {}'.format(err)]}

        return {'payload': booking_schema.dump(booking_item)}, 200

def schedule_notif(timestamp, token, n_id):
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    app.apscheduler.add_job(id=n_id, func=send_push, trigger='date', run_date=date, args=(token,
                                                                                        "Your have 30 "
                                                                                        "minutes "
                                                                                        "untill your "
                                                                                        "booking "
                                                                                        ,
                                                                                        "Your have 30 "
                                                                                        "minutes untill "
                                                                                        "your booking"
                                                                                        , n_id))


def send_push(token, title, message, n_id):
    push_service = FCMNotification(api_key=api_key)


    try:
        registration_id = token.token
        if registration_id:
            message_title = title
            message_body = message
            data = {
                "title": title,
                "body": message,
                "type": "booking_reminder"
            }
            push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title,
                                              message_body=message_body, data_message=data, timeout=30)

    except Exception as err:
        return {'payload': {}, 'success': False, 'errors': ["{}".format(err)]}, 400
```

I don't know what is the problem, maybe that server stops my scheduler. 
Can you please help me understand what i am doing wrong?

Thanks!